# What happens when a deprecated optimization flag is passed to GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

In my stack configuration i have a list of optimization flags that i pass to GHC normally, but i tried the latest version of GHC which deprecated one of them. During compilation GHC gave me a warning about this, but still compiled everything.

What actually happens when this occurs? Are there any consequences? Does it just ignore that flag but still pass the rest of my optimization flags?

Thanks

Comment: What does the GHC user's guide for the relevant GHC version say about the specific deprecated flag?

Comment: Generally speaking, if some feature is deprecated it doesn't mean anything right now – it should still work as before. All that deprecation expresses is that the feature won't be supported anymore _in the future_, so you'd better stop using it now to avoid failures with future releases.

Comment: @sjakobi -funfolding-keeness-factor=⟨n⟩ This factor was deprecated in GHC 9.0.1. See #15304 for details. Users who need to control inlining should rather consider -funfolding-use-threshold=⟨n⟩.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an unknown flag to GHC, you'll get an error and compilation will fail.

When using a deprecated flag, on the other hand, it depends on the flag. For example, using `-auto` will warn you that you should use `-fprof-auto-exported` but it will trigger the latter anyway. It's just that maybe in a few versions of GHC, the deprecated flag will disappear. For `-funfolding-keeness-factor`, GHC tells us that it's no longer respected, so you can pass the flag but it should have no effect on the compilation.